# Shiny server crashing

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server

Background:
I am running shiny-server on a RHEL 5 box and it keeps crashing in a non reproducible way. Seems like that node.js has something to do with the error..

The error is the following:

```
 Error: write EIO
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

The log from /var/log/shiny-server.log

```
[2015-07-15 17:28:20.982] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShiny Server v1.4.0.718 (Node.js v0.10.21)
            ^[[32m[2015-07-15 17:28:20.984] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing pidfile /foplocal/app/shiny-server/shiny-server.pid
            ^[[32m[2015-07-15 17:28:20.985] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
            ^[[32m[2015-07-15 17:28:21.039] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStarting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
            ^[[31m[2015-07-15 20:17:50.196] [ERROR] shiny-server - ^[[39mUncaught exception: Error: write EIO
            ^[[31m[2015-07-15 20:17:50.197] [ERROR] shiny-server - ^[[39mError: write EIO
                at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
                at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
            ^[[32m[2015-07-15 20:17:50.198] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStopping listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
            ^[[32m[2015-07-15 20:17:50.198] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShutting down worker processes (with notification)
```

**Session info**

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/V5cv0f7Gmtk

Any help would be very much appreciated! Worst case I will put in a cron job in place that monitors the service and starts it on failure..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I was a bit rushed in placing a bounty on this question.

The answer was in the link that Peter had posted.

Version 1.3.0.403 of shiny server had a bug which did not play well with packages like DT. Upgrading to atleast version 1.4.0.721 should be enough to take care of the issue.